# asp.net Javascript serialiser

Tags: asp.net

Hi Im having trouble getting the Javascript serialiser to convert this Json string to alist of strings

```
{'Roles':['Role1','Role2','Role3','Role4']}";

(new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize< List<String> >( strInput )
```

it returns an empty list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
['Role1','Role2','Role3','Role4']
```

would be

```
 List<string>
```

What you have with

```
{'Roles':['Role1','Role2','Role3','Role4']}
```

is

```
 Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are leaving out the top-level node which contains the array. That JSON could actually represent an object Foo with one property Roles that could be a List of string.